# Application Insights + Azure Service Bus - Capture message from the bus in dependency tracking

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I am looking into how the app insights work with different types of dependencies. I have a question on using the AppInsights ASP Net Core sdk with Messaging Service Bus sdk.

How can I capture messages to service bus while sending or receiving using this sdk in dependency? I understand that this is not something we would like to log all the time and I will make it configurable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own sender and implement the desired logic inside the `SendMessageAsync` method:

```cs
public class TelemetryEnabledServiceBusSender : ServiceBusSender
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

    internal TelemetryEnabledServiceBusSender(ServiceBusClient client, string topic, TelemetryClient telemetryClient) : base(client, topic)
    {
        this.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }

    public override async Task SendMessageAsync(ServiceBusMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message.Body.ToString());

        await base.SendMessageAsync(message, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

use it like this:

```cs
var serviceBusSender = new TelemetryEnabledServiceBusSender(serviceBusClient, serviceBusData.Topic, telemetryClient);
await serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(message);
```

Logging processed messages is even simpler and can be done using the `ServiceBusProcessor`

```cs
serviceBusProcessor.ProcessMessageAsync += ProcessMessageAsync;

...

private async Task ProcessMessageAsync(ProcessMessageEventArgs arg)
{
    telemetryClient.TrackTrace(arg.Message.Body.ToString());

    ...
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I did the same with a custom DependencyTelemetry operation as below:

```
var telemetry = new DependencyTelemetry(
            "Azure Service Bus",
            _serviceBusClient.FullyQualifiedNamespace,
            "Receive",
            string.Empty
        );
using var operation =
            _telemetryClient.StartOperation(telemetry);
telemetry.Data = receivedMessage;
// Catch
telemetry.Success = false;
_telemetryClient.TrackException(e);
...
telemetry.Success = true;
_telemetryClient.TrackTrace("Done");
_telemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding my approach as an answer here as it is too long to comment.

```
        var telemetry = new DependencyTelemetry(
            "Azure Service Bus",
            _serviceBusClient.FullyQualifiedNamespace,
            "ServiceBusReceiver.Receive",
            string.Empty
        );
        using var operation =
            _telemetryClient.StartOperation(telemetry);
        try
        {
            var receivedMessage = await _serviceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();
            if (receivedMessage?.Body is not null)
            {
                message = receivedMessage.Body.ToString();
                telemetry.Data = message;
                // do something
            }
            telemetry.Success = true;
            //Consider set telemetry duration
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // log exception
            _telemetryClient.TrackException(e);
            telemetry.Success = false;
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _telemetryClient.TrackTrace("Done");
            _telemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);
        }
```

Thanks to @Peter Bons